# Inserting values from one custom field to another using Anonymous Debug Window

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

we've found some of our records currently have a blank field which we need to populate using the values from a different custom field, because this will be a one time thing im writing a script in the anonymous debug window which will do this, so far i have written :

```
 List<producto__c> prodOrdersIDs  = [SELECT id, name, prod2__c, project__c,  Quote__c from producto__c where prod2__c = null and Quote__c != null];
for(producto__c po: prodOrdersIDs ){

   List<producto__c> QLIproduct2Id = [SELECT Quote__r.product2id from producto__c];
        if(po.prod2__c = null){
            po.prod2__c = po.Quote.product2id;
    }
    update po.prod2__c;
}
```

however this bring through the error : condition expression must be of type Boolean.

any idea where this is occurring would be greatly appreciated cheers

UPDATE:

this will now run but now comes through says theres too many future calls: 11

```
List<productorder__c> prodOrdersIDs  = [SELECT id, name, product2__c, project__c, Quote_line_item__r.product2id,  Quote_Line_Item__c from productorder__c where product2__c = null and Quote_Line_Item__c != null];
List<productorder__c> QLIproduct2Id = [SELECT Quote_line_item__r.product2id from productorder__c];

for(productorder__c po: prodOrdersIDs ){
        if(po.product2__c == null){
            po.product2__c = po.Quote_line_item__r.product2id;
    }
    update po;
}
```

Comment: Doing a query in a for loop like you do is not a good way !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the equality operator (`==`) in your conditional statement, rather than the assignment operator (`=`).

Your code also has other issues which will need to be addressed:

- `SELECT` from `Producto__c` into a `List<ProductOrder__c>`.
- SOQL query inside a `for` loop.
- DML operation (`update`) within a `for` loop.
- DML operation on a field (`po.prod2__c`) rather than an object (in this case `po`).

Since this is a one off operation, you may be able to get away with the second two if you have less than 99 `ProductOrder__c` objects (since you've already used 1 of the 100 SOQL limit in your first query), but I would recommend trying to bulkify anyway by adding the objects that need to be updated to a list and then calling `update` on that list..

Comment: Hi, the first bullet point was a typo on here, however with the DML update within the loop i get 'DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Id' but when i try to change to update just the 'po' this arrives SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: ProductOrder__c.Quote_Line_Item__r

Comment: @ClevelandDan Can you update the code in your question (preferably my adding it underneath your existing content)? As it stands the code in the question should not give you that error (or in fact compile, as it has other syntax errors).

Comment: Edited it above

Comment: @ClevelandDan Based on the 'too many future calls' error you have a callout in a trigger somewhere. Moving the DML operation out of the loop should fix this (unless your trigger is poorly written). Remove `update po` and move it below the loop and change it to `update prodOrderIds`. You can also get rid of your second SOQL query as you never use the results.

Comment: FYI, `update prodOrderIds` will make your code call save on records that don't need it, leading to less efficient processing and erroneous LastUpdate information. Best practice would be to set the modified `po` into a new list and save that list only.

Comment: @Peter Considering this is a one-off exercise in the Developer Console I wouldn't be massively concerned about this, unless there were very large volumes. It's definitely a valid point though.

Comment: Fair enough on performance. But there will still be records that are marked as updated that weren't. In some instances this is not desirable.

Comment: Also, someone else finding this might be looking for a way to structure there code that will go into production. I would rather that person find a best practice than a "good enough for exec anonymous". :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the problem with the equality operator, here is a suggestion for your code, as you are doing some potentially dangerous things.

Your code:

```
List<producto__c> prodOrdersIDs  = [SELECT id, name, prod2__c, project__c,  Quote__c 
                                   from producto__c 
                                   where prod2__c = null and Quote__c != null];

for(producto__c po: prodOrdersIDs ){

  List<producto__c> QLIproduct2Id = [SELECT Quote__r.product2id 
                                     from producto__c]; <--same sObject queried twice
                                                <-- no where clause is a bad idea
    if(po.prod2__c = null){
        po.prod2__c = po.Quote.product2id;
    }                                   ^---probably this is quote__r ???
    update po.prod2__c; <--this is almost guaranteed to cause problems when done inside a loop
                ^--also, youdon't call update on a field, rather on an sobject or list of sobjects
}
```

Try this:

```
List<producto__c> prodOrdersForUpdate = new List<producto__c>();
List<producto__c> prodOrdersIDs  = [SELECT id, name, quote__r.product2Id, prod2__c, project__c
                                   from producto__c 
                                   where prod2__c = null and Quote__c != null];

for(producto__c po: prodOrdersIDs ){

    if(po.prod2__c = null){
        po.prod2__c = po.quote__r.product2id;
    }
    prodOrdersForUpdate.add(po);
}
update prodOrdersForUpdate;
```